# Page locks up on re-opening amp-lightbox

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

My client asked me to build a purely AMP based site. On certain pages we have an amp-carousel that opens an amp-lightbox set up according to the documentation. The problem is that if someone opens up the lightbox and then closes it, upon trying to re-open the images the page locks up and requires a refresh.

Example Page: https://www.bookitdirect.com/big-bus-tours/las-vegas

I have tried various different things to work around the issue, but I still can't find the root issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. I've filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/17423).

Comment: I couldn't be sure and wanted to make sure it wasn't something obvious that I overlooks as someone new to AMP.